# Add SAML assertions to WCF Client without using WIF

Tags: wcf, mono, wif, saml, claims-based-identity

I have a WCF service which is hosted inside a WebApp which uses Claims Based Authentication to authenticate users with ACS and ADFS.

The client is running on Mono so I can't [use WIF to make it "just work"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003330/in-a-wcf-client-how-can-i-add-saml-2-0-assertion-to-soap-header).

I can request the assertions (SAML ticket) using [the method described here](http://bit.ly/Ux0RIu).

Is there another way to insert the assertion into the WCF Client's request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post by the Microsoft Solutions UK provides a way to do this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/08/17/federated-security-how-to-setup-and-call-a-wcf-service-secured-by-adfs-2-0.aspx