# WCF - Custom Credentials & Security Tokens

Tags: wcf, servicebehavior

I'm fairly new to WCF development and have run into a couple problems whilst learning the framework. I have a service api which must support both REST & SOAP. So far this has been easy to implement especially with WCF4 and routing.

I am currently working on authorization and have managed to extend AuthorizationManager by creating two new manager classes: "ApiKeyAuthorizationManager" & "ApiKeyAndTokenAuthorizationManager"

Most of my services will require an ApiKey and Token (GUIDS) to be present; when initially authenticating, you simply need a valid ApiKey and password to receive a Token.

So far REST is working perfectly as the Authorization managers look to the query string to get ApiKey and/or Token.

So for example a service uri would look like:
*http://api.domain.com/Service/Operation/{someVariableValue}?ApiKey=GUID&Token=GUID

My problem now comes with authorizing SOAP service calls. I've done a little bit of research and have come to a few conclusions I wanted to verify are correct before implementing.

In order to authorize SOAP with custom credentials I should:

1. Create custom service token ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872.aspx))
2. Extend WCF by creating a custom SecurityTokenProvider, SecurityTokenAuthenticator, and SecurityTokenSerializer ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730868.aspx))
3. Extend WCF by creating custom AuthorizationPolicies ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751416.aspx))

*Am I on the right track for this? Are all these steps needed to fit my scenario? Seems like so much customization for just verifying a credential made up of two GUIDs.*

Thanks!

---

**[EDIT #1]**

This has been a very difficult task.  Custom credentials and security tokens is nearly undocumented.  Finding quality blog posts itself has proven near impossible.  I've kept plugging away and am so close to have a working solution.  I've even hit the same road blocks as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563037/wcf-authentication-with-custom-clientcredentials-what-is-the-clientcredentialtyp).

When I try to access my service to uncover the wsdl or mex I receive this error:

```
The service encountered an error.

An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.SymmetricSecurityBindingElement
Error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: parameters ----> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: parameters
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateTokenAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, SecurityTokenParameters parameters, Boolean isOptional)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateWsspSignedSupportingTokensAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, Collection`1 signed, Collection`1 signedEncrypted, Collection`1 optionalSigned, Collection`1 optionalSignedEncrypted)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateWsspSupportingTokensAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, Collection`1 signed, Collection`1 signedEncrypted, Collection`1 endorsing, Collection`1 signedEndorsing, Collection`1 optionalSigned, Collection`1 optionalSignedEncrypted, Collection`1 optionalEndorsing, Collection`1 optionalSignedEndorsing, AddressingVersion addressingVersion)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateWsspSupportingTokensAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, Collection`1 signed, Collection`1 signedEncrypted, Collection`1 endorsing, Collection`1 signedEndorsing, Collection`1 optionalSigned, Collection`1 optionalSignedEncrypted, Collection`1 optionalEndorsing, Collection`1 optionalSignedEndorsing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.ExportSymmetricSecurityBindingElement(SymmetricSecurityBindingElement binding, MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

If you have any idea what might be causing this I'd love some help.

---

**[EDIT #2]**

It seems Microsoft doesn't want to update their samples to show how to allow wsdl support for custom credentials / tokens.  [See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1e3a71bc-7cef-414e-80dc-711cdea370e0).
Anyone have an idea how to get this working? What's the point of making a framework extensible if there's no documentation how to extend it?!?

---

**[EDIT #3]**

As stated in my comment below...
I have TransportWithMessageCredential working just fine using UserNameSecurityToken.  Unfortunately, my services will end up requiring custom tokens when it's time to implement some more advanced features that I have planned.

*What I'm looking for as an answer would be:*

**How to support custom service credentials and tokens *with* WSDL support?**

Currently, following Microsoft's examples, you can only use custom credentials by using ChannelFactory and creating a custom binding on the client. I would rather not deal with that.

If this question remains unanswered, I'll keep upping the bounty. As soon as I can get this all working I'll write up a blog tutorial on all the steps required to creating a custom security solution.

Comment: Well I'm on the right track, however this is a very undocumented area in WCF which I find surprising. You can follow along the MSDN articles mentioned above but MS also provides the solution files to go along with them here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that the return on investment into creating custom credentials and tokens is just not worth the amount of time I am putting into this. Hopefully in the future, MS will come around with some better support in this area.

I've decided to do what I can with UserName message credential type. I'll leave this question open for answer and will reward the bounty if someone can still resolve it.

Comment: UserNameSecurityToken is working just find for now, though I will end up requiring custom tokens when it's time to implement some more advanced features that I have planned.  What I'm looking for as an answer would be "How to support custom service credentials and tokens with WSDL support".  If this question remains unanswered, I'll keep upping the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise you look to Windows Identity Foundation, and move in the direction of claim based security/federation. This model supports custom credentials much better as they are just a different set of claims.

Comment: I've been learning WIF and have read Vittorio Bertocci's book on the subject. However, I'm not sure creating my own STS IdP is needed here. Will definitely consider this as an option though. Much thanks for your input.