# WCF Service with custom security token

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

When I am trying to export metadata I am getting error.My binding code is

```
HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

// the transport security binding element will be configured to require a username token
TransportSecurityBindingElement transportSecurity = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
transportSecurity.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UsernameTokenParameters());
//transportSecurity.ProtectTokens = true;
//   transportSecurity.ProtectTokens = true;
// transportSecurity.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UsernameTokenParameters());
transportSecurity.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
transportSecurity.IncludeTimestamp = true;
//transportSecurity.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.EncryptBeforeSign;

// here you can require secure transport, in which case you'd probably replace HTTP with HTTPS as well
transportSecurity.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
//transportSecurity.IncludeTimestamp = false;

TextMessageEncodingBindingElement me = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);

return new CustomBinding(transportSecurity, httpTransport);
```

Following is the error and trace.Please help...

The service encountered an error.

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement
Error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: parameters ----> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: parameters
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateTokenAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, SecurityTokenParameters parameters, Boolean isOptional)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateTokenAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, SecurityTokenParameters parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateWsspSignedSupportingTokensAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, Collection`1 signed, Collection`1 signedEncrypted, Collection`1 optionalSigned, Collection`1 optionalSignedEncrypted)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityPolicy.CreateWsspSupportingTokensAssertion(MetadataExporter exporter, Collection`1 signed, Collection`1 signedEncrypted, Collection`1 endorsing, Collection`1 signedEndorsing, Collection`1 optionalSigned, Collection`1 optionalSignedEncrypted, Collection`1 optionalEndorsing, Collection`1 optionalSignedEndorsing, AddressingVersion addressingVersion)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.ExportTransportSecurityBindingElement(TransportSecurityBindingElement binding, ITransportTokenAssertionProvider transportTokenAssertionProvider, MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.ExportPolicyForTransportTokenAssertionProviders(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement.System.ServiceModel.Description.IPolicyExportExtension.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: http://www.techques.com/question/1-4157520/WCF---Custom-Credentials---Security-Tokens

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157520/wcf-custom-credentials-security-tokens

Comment: http://1987.io/questions/714992/wcf-custom-credentials-security-tokens

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LKDwxurN

Comment: http://quabr.com/4157520/wcf-custom-credentials-security-tokens