# Using WCF service how can I audit an application user's action?

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication

I am implementing a 3 tiered application.  I am using WCF as my service/BLL layer.  When calling the service my authentication allows a certain domain account access preventing unwanted traffic and only maintaining a single account per application.

In addition to this I also want to audit the application's end user that is performing the action.

For example, my app user, lets call him Bob, updates a purchase order.  The application calls the UpdatePO() method in my service using the user id/password specific to that app.  The app is authorized.  Now the update can occur.  When performing the update I need to verify that Bob can perform the action and log it to my database.

I will need to do this with almost any update service calls and even some read calls.  I don't want to pass a parameter with each method if possible.  **Is there a way to pass a second set of credentials to a service which will be used as my audit credentials?**

I don't want to have to maintain a group will all users that can call the service.  The service authorization itself and the maintenance of the service accounts must be kept to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MessageHeaders to do this.

**From Client**

```
var auditHeader = new MessageHeader<string>("Bob");
var proxy = new MyClient();
using(var contextScope = new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel)){
  OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                                  auditHeader.GetUntypedHeader("string","System"));
   proxy.MyMethod();
}
proxy.Close();
```

**At Server**

```
class MyService : IMyContract{
   public void MyMethod()   {
      var who = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("string","System");
      // use it ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I've decided to use this method. It seems a bit cleaner than the other proposed option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple suggestions:

---

You can implement your own auth 'token' in WCF, which it would use to pass the credentials, and you could have it include both the application and the user credentials. However implementing custom security tokens in WCF is a real pain... expect it to take a couple days to get it working :) That would let you more easily isolate the authorization and authentication bits instead of passing it as parameters to every method.

For implementation details, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730868.aspx).

---

You could have all your methods take 1 parameter; some kind of Message base class that contains the user credentials, and extend it for each specific message type.

In code:

```
[DataContract]
public class MessageBase {
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class UpdatePOMessage : MessageBase {
}

[OperationContract]
public void UpdatePO(UpdatePOMessage message) { /* do work */ }
```

Then you could implement a custom `IOperationInvoker` or another WCF extension point that looks at the method parameter, makes sure it implements `MessageBase` and if it does, validates and audits the credentials.

---

IMO the 2nd way is a bit more "hacky". In my latest production application, we do the 1st option... pass a complete custom security token from the client, instead of the built-in WCF security types. In fact I have a lengthy StackOverflow question that I made back when I was having problems with it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563037/wcf-authentication-with-custom-clientcredentials-what-is-the-clientcredentialty).